# best way to cache image url from my webservice?

Tags: ios, objective-c, web-services, caching

i have implement one application in ARC format. but i want to cache some image url(s) in cache folder of library .
any idea?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Create a dictionary and write the image url to them !

Comment: can you give sample or tutorial for that?

Comment: http://blog.mugunthkumar.com/coding/ios-tutorial-image-cache-and-loading-thumbnails-using-mknetworkkit/      please try this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope it's can help you. I use [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) with my all projects.

using :

add your viewcontroller  : `#import "UIImageView+WebCache.h"`

```
[yourImageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"ImageUrl"]];
```

you need to add MapKit and ImageIO to the project. if you didn't add

To do that:

1. Click on the project at the top of the project navigator in Xcode
2. Select the 'Build Phases' tab.
3. Open up the 'Link Binary with Libraries' box.
4. Click the '+'.
5. Add MapKit and ImageIO frameworks.

Comment: i do that but in my ARC code whole sdwebimage vie class puted as ARC flag like : **"-fno-objc-arc"** in bulit phases .but getting till now error in this class --> ** #import "SDWebImageCompat.h"** error is : **SDWebImage is ARC only.Either turn on ARC for project or use -fobj-arc flag**.
but i already added flag in built phases file.

how to solve this error in ARC code ,please give solution for that?

Comment: `SDWebImage` is ARC, but you are flagging the file as none ARC with `-fno-objc-arc`

Comment: then what have to do for ARC classes of SDWebimage?

Answer (score 1):

You can [`NSURLCache`](https://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLCache_Class/Reference/Reference.html) which will actually be used by default when using [`NSURLConnection`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

The other option is to use [`NSCache`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/NSCache_Class/Reference/Reference.html) which is specially build for for caching objects, it will automaticly release any objects it holds when the system need more memory. It works about the same as [`NSDictionary`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Create a shared instance of the [`NSCache`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/NSCache_Class/Reference/Reference.html) some where then do something like:

```
UIImage *image = [self.imagaeCache objectForKey:urlString];
if (!image) {
    // load the image from the URL
}
```

Just remember to add the downloaded image to the cache:

```
[self.imagaeCache setObject:image forKey:urlString];
```