# Images changes in tableview after every scroll

Tags: ios, multithreading, uitableview, asynchronous

Hi i am pretty new to IOS so pardon for silly questions . I am working on an app which loads large images in a tableview. I am fetching local images asynchronously and storing into a Dictionary for caching  **The problem is when i scroll the tableview image changes and resize with a lag  and sometimes the app itself  crashes if i add more images and scroll a lot of time**
Here is my code :

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:
(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell =
        (UITableViewCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell =
            [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle
                                   reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
      NSError *attributesError = nil;

    NSString *workSpacePath = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory]
                            stringByAppendingPathComponent:[images objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    NSDictionary *fileAttributes = [[NSFileManager defaultManager]
                                 attributesOfItemAtPath:workSpacePath error:&attributesError];
    NSNumber * fileSizeNumber = [fileAttributes objectForKey:NSFileSize];
    long long int fileKBSize = [fileSizeNumber longLongValue]/1024;

   cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    NSString *descriptionString =  [images objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSLog(@"descriptionString :%@",descriptionString);
    if ([[despDectionary objectForKey:descriptionString] length] > 0) {
            cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[despDectionary objectForKey:descriptionString]];
    }
    else {
            cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"File Description";
    }

    if([self.cacheImages objectForKey:descriptionString]!=nil)
    {
     cell.imageView.image = [self.cacheImages valueForKey:descriptionString];
    }

    else
    {
    dispatch_queue_t bg = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0ul);

    dispatch_async(bg,^{

    UIImage *myimage=[UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:workSpacePath]];

   NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(myimage, 0.2);
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
    UIImage *thumb = [image makethumbnail:CGSizeMake(110, 70)];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
   // [cell.setNeedsLayout];
     cell.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 110, 70);
    if([tableView indexPathForCell:cell].row== indexPath.row)
    {
    //cell.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 110, 70);
    NSString *imagename = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[despDectionary objectForKey:descriptionString]];
     [self.cacheImages setValue:thumb forKey:imagename];
           cell.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 110, 70);
      NSLog(@"cacheImages -- %@",self.cacheImages);
    cell.imageView.image = [self.cacheImages valueForKey:imagename];
   // [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
    }//[tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
      });
    });
  }
  // NSLog(@" Dictionary CACHE IMAGES is @%",self.cacheImages);
    cell.detailTextLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

    UIButton * button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(250, 0, 49,56);
    [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"deletButotn.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    button.tag = indexPath.row;
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(deleteButtonAction:)  forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:button];


    return  cell;
}
```

Comment: Check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19111758/best-way-to-cache-image-url-from-my-webservice

Comment: Thanks for your reply but i am using local images not web images and i guess SDWebImage is for web images

Comment: did you end up finding a solution for the resizing problem?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using SDWebimage to manage this... So easy and consistent.

https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage

Comment: Isn't SDWebimage for webimages? i am working with local images , like images taken from camera is added to tableview

Comment: I see, yes it is for web images... Then your problem is that you aren't dispatching to the main_queue.. Read about this.. And I'm not sure about the lagging, maybe you could check NSCache, it can be handy in such situations... Can I help you more?

Comment: Thanks alot for your reply Mr_bem. I am dispatching main queue can you suggest some tutorial for implementing NSCache in this scenario?

Comment: No problems! Sorry! didn't see the main_queue dispatch! Then maybe the lagging is caused there, only dispatch when you want to update the view, thats the best practice for this.

However, you can use the NSCache EXACTLY as you use your NSDictionary, just change the type and thats it.

It manages itself in low level, but the data there don't stay forever, they are automatically released when they're not needed.

Check the documentations for it, nothing more than the dictionary in the use ;D

Anything else?

Comment: I changed it to NSCache .. The issue is still there :(

Answer (score 0):

Using `NSCache` or `NSDictionary` which are directly storing images - especially if you're using it asynchronous is very expensive. You can `Profile` your app by using `Instruments` and look for if there are memory leaks or allocation problems. I think you might be getting too many allocation problems.

As a solution, I recommend you to use `NSDictionary` or `NSCache` for storing **not images but paths of images**. You can also use `NSOperation` to get image from its path stored in your caching variable. By the way you would get the images asynchronously.

For example, there is a created `ImageRecord` class that includes *path of image* and *imageID*. In that class, we have a function that gets image from disk. Calling that function asynchronously or as NSOperation is possible though:

```
@implementation ImageRecord

NSString *filePath;
NSString *imageID;
// Ignoring getters, setters and other functions

// Here is our function :
-(UIImage *)getImageFromDisk{
    UIImage *image = [UIImage new];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfMappedFile:self.filePath];
    if (data) {
        image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
        if (!image) {
            return nil;
        }
    }
    return image;
}
```

and in the cellForRowAtIndexPath function :

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    // example caching variable: We have a list of imageRecords with ID's and filePaths 
    // We're using indexPath as imageID of imageRecord
    imagesCache = (NSDictionary *) [self getImagesCache]
    ImageRecord *aRecord = [imagesCache objectForKey:indexPath.row];
    // I didn't call directly but you can try to call the function asynchronously.
    cell.imageView.image  = [aRecord getImageFromDisk];
    return cell;
}
```

There would be syntax errors, I'm sorry for that but I hope the logic of example would be a helpful for you to overcome the problem